# Parent Component losing state immediately after re render Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I'm very new to React and I'm trying to write an app that will automatically display a Login page on startup, and when the user successfully logs in the parent component updates its state to render the Dashboard component instead of Login.

What I am finding is that when the user logs in, it updates the parent components state correctly and displays the Dashboard component for a second but then its state changes again and re-renders the Login component. I think something is causing the state to reset, but I'm not sure what.

User.js:

```
class User extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            isLoggedIn: false
        }

        this.updateUser = this.updateUser.bind(this);
    }

    updateUser(newEmail) {
        console.log(`Entered User.updateUser, email: ${newEmail}`);
        this.setState({
            email: newEmail,
            isLoggedIn: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
            return <Dashboard/>
        }

        return <Login updateTheUser={this.updateUser}/>
    }
}

export default User;
```

Login.js:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        };

        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleResponse = this.handleResponse.bind(this);
    }

    handleEmailChange(event) {
        this.setState({email: event.target.value})
    }

    handlePasswordChange(event) {
        this.setState({password: event.target.value})
    }

    handleResponse(res) {
        if (res.ok) {
            alert('Login Successful!');
            this.props.updateTheUser(this.state.email);
        }
        else if (res.status === 401) {
            alert('Wrong Username or Password');
        }        
    }

    async sendLoginRequest(data) {
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/login/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: data,
        })
        .then(this.handleResponse)
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert('Server error, please try again.');
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        const data = `{"email": "${this.state.email}", "password": "${this.state.password}"}`
        this.sendLoginRequest(data);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div id="container" className="col-md-12" align="center">
                <div id="vertical-center-div"className="col-sm-4 card bg-light">
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Label className="display-4 text-secondary">Login</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Control type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} placeholder="Email" required/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                            <Form.Control type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} placeholder="Password" required/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                            <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Remember me" />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button id="submitButton" variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Dashboard.js:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expenses: [],
            incomings: []
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <>
            <p className="display-4">Dashboard</p>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that in `Login.js` you need to prevent default submit behaviour with `event.preventDefault()`

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const data = `{"email": "${this.state.email}", "password": "${this.state.password}"}`
        this.sendLoginRequest(data);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Filip, I tried this but it seems to prevent the form from submitting a request and re-rendering of the Login component

Comment: Hi, I believe there is also a mistake in `User.js`, you are setting `isLoggedIn` to `false`

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so when the component is re-rendered it sets `isLoggedIn` to `false` again? So how to I declare it without setting it to false?

Comment: I meant in `updateUser` method, you are setting user's email to newEmail and isLoggedIn status to false. Your application never reaches `this.state.isLoggedIn === true`.